# How to utilize source control for Azure Functions in the Azure Portal

Tags: c#, azure, version-control, azure-functions

This may be out of the scope of the portal in its current state but I'm wondering how people are managing their functions with source control in the portal itself or if they are at all.

I really like the way the portal is built out and would love to utilize it to quickly build out serverless functions but I haven't yet found a way that we can link up to a github repo or implement some sort of source control within the portal. I know I can develop within Visual Studio and publish up to Azure but I feel like we end up losing a lot of functionality that is only in the portal currently for quick set up.

Is there something I am missing with the current architecture of Azure functions and there is a way to do this? Or are most people just developing within VS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Functions in two different ways:

1. Portal dev mode where you author your functions in the portal. There is no support for source control in this mode.
2. Client development mode, which is preferred. You author your functions locally, and deploy them either from VS, or by setting up Continuous Deployment from GitHub, VSTS, Bitbucket, ...

Note that these two approaches are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid this might be the case.